# Grouping json content

Tags: json, swift, group-by

This is my json:

```
[
  {
    "category" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "text" : "cat1"
    },
    "id" : 1,
    "title" : "book1"
  },{
    "category" : {
      "id" : 2,
      "text" : "cat2"
    },
    "id" : 2,
    "title" : "book2"
  },{
    "category" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "text" : "cat1"
    },
    "id" : 3,
    "title" : "book3"
  }
]
```

How can I grouping it by category? i want to use them in different **collectionView**

Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
        let str = """
[
{
"category" : {
"id" : 1,
"text" : "cat1"
},
"id" : 1,
"title" : "book1"
},{
"category" : {
"id" : 2,
"text" : "cat2"
},
"id" : 2,
"title" : "book2"
},{
"category" : {
"id" : 1,
"text" : "cat1"
},
"id" : 3,
"title" : "book3"
}
]


"""

        do {

            let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from: Data(str.utf8))

            print(res)

            let dic = Dictionary(grouping: res, by: { $0.category.text})

            print(dic) // this dictionary is your new data source key is title of section value is sections rows 
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let category: Category
    let id: Int
    let title: String
}

struct Category: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let text: String
}
```

Comment: Your code lacks `Root` type definition. An can be formatted better.

Answer (score 2):

Define your JSON codable classes as follows.

```
typealias Result = [ResultElement]

struct ResultElement: Codable {
    let category: Category
    let id: Int
    let title: String
}

struct Category: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let text: String
}
```

Now, Iterate Result array after JSON parsing using `JSONDecoder` and compare Category struct by equal operator and group it. Since `Int` and `String` inside Category struct conforms to `Equatable` protocol by default, Category struct can also be compared using `Equatable` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Structs

   ```
   //MARK: - MyData
   public struct MyData {

       public var category : Category
       public var id : Int
       public var title : String

   }

   //MARK: - Category
   public struct Category {

       public var id : Int
       public var text : String

   }
   ```
2. Create Model

   ```
   func createData () -> [MyData] {
       let c1 = Category.init(id: 1, text: "Cat1")
       let d1 = MyData.init(category: c1, id: 1, title: "Book1")
       let c2 = Category.init(id: 2, text: "Cat2")
       let d2 = MyData.init(category: c2, id: 2, title: "Book2")
       let c3 = Category.init(id: 1, text: "Cat1")
       let d3 = MyData.init(category: c3, id: 3, title: "Book3")

       return [d1, d2, d3]

   }
   ```
3. Group your data

   ```
       let ungroupedData = createData()
       print("Ungrouped\n")
       print(ungroupedData)
       let groupedData = Dictionary(grouping: ungroupedData, by: {$0.category.text})
       print("\nGrouped\n")
       print(groupedData)

       groupedData["Cat1"] // get cat1 array list
   ```